# PHP: call_user_func_array: pass by reference issue

Tags: php, function-calls

The below function generates error when a function contains referenced arguments eg:

```
function test(&$arg, &$arg2)
{
  // some code
}
```

Now I can not use `call_user_func_array` for above function, it will generate an error.

How to solve this problem?

I do need to use `call_user_func_array`.

Also assume that i don't know beforehand whether they are passed by reference or passed by value.

Thanks

Comment: It would be worth while for you to unaccept the current answer as it is quite literally wrong (not to mention has bad advice by abusing objects which changes the semantics of the problem completely): http://codepad.viper-7.com/j3GOps

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A great workaround was posted on http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.call-user-func-array.php#91503

```
function executeHook($name, $type='hooks'){ 
    $args = func_get_args(); 
    array_shift($args); 
    array_shift($args); 
    //Rather stupid Hack for the call_user_func_array(); 
    $Args = array(); 
    foreach($args as $k => &$arg){ 
        $Args[$k] = &$arg; 
    } 
    //End Hack 
    $hooks = &$this->$type; 
    if(!isset($hooks[$name])) return false; 
    $hook = $hooks[$name]; 
    call_user_func_array($hook, $Args); 
}
```

The actual hack is surrounded by comments.

Comment: thank you man, saved my life! this is definitely the correct answer

Comment: Spoke too soon … While this removes the error, it wouldn't let me manipulate the referenced variable inside the callable.

Comment: For PHP 5.6 and above declare the function with `, &...$args` and then call the hook as simple as `$hook(...$args)`.

Answer (score 22):

When storing your parameters in the array, make sure you are storing a reference to those parameters, it should work fine.

Ie:

```
call_user_func_array("test", array(&param1, &param2));
```

Comment: but what if i don't know beforehand whether they are passed by reference or passed by value?

Comment: Then figure out a way to determine that, or make them all pass by reference would be my suggestion. Not much else you can do I'm afraid.

Comment: Myles: what if I don't know amount of arguments in the array?

Comment: @ymakux ultimately you need an array of references. You'll be passing *something* so just create an array from whatever that something is.

Comment: yes, right, seems call_user_func_array becomes useless in my case, i have to write spaghetti code instead of this                         switch(count($args)) {
                            case 0:
                            $class->{$method}();
                            break;
                            case 1:
                        }