# __call method needs to know when to pass var by reference or by value

Tags: php

I have an object that uses the magic **__call** method to call methods on different objects.

There are times when this method will be used to call a method that requires one or more of its parameters to be a reference.

As of php 5.3 call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated so I cant rely on passing the arguments by reference. I need to predict if the arguments need to be passed by reference or value!

I will try to explain this in code. I have the following two classes:

- Main_Object
- Extension_Object

*note:* there is no inheritance structure between the two classes.

```
class Main_Object  {

 public function __call($method, $arguments)
 {
  // check this method is in an extended class
  // …

  $ext = new Extension_Object();

  // call method in extension object
  return call_user_func_array(array($ext, $method), $arguments);
 }
}

class Extension_Object {

 // takes two arguments
 public function foo($p1, $p2)
 {
  // ...
 }

 // takes two arguments, the first being a reference
 public function bar(&$p1, $p2)
 {
  // ...
 }
}
```

Currently I cant find a way to call bar() without generating a PHP error or warning

```
$obj = new Main_Object();

// works as expected
$obj->foo($bacon, $cheese);

// MESSAGE call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated
$obj->bar(&$bacon, $cheese);

// WARNING parameter 1 expected to be a reference
$obj->bar($bacon, $cheese);
```

Comment: Why do you want to pass a reference?  In my experience, 99% of uses for references are actually quite doable without needing to use the reference...  So unless you have a **need** to use references, I wouldn't worry about it...

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I need to pass a reference to an object because the method may change some of its properties. I cant return the object as the method needs to return something else. I could return an array of values and use list() to assign the returned elements to their own variables but this feels dirty.

Comment: You don't need references for that.  In PHP 5.0+, objects are passed by reference only (you need to explicitly `clone` the object to break a reference).  See [the docs on the subject](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php).  So no, you don't need to pass by reference...

Answer (score 1):

You could set allow_call_time_pass_reference = 1; but it's far from a good solution. There doesn't seem to be another way. Reflection might yield an answer, but I personally don't know enough about this particular issue to really advise on that...

[Is it possible to pass parameters by reference using call_user_func_array()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295016/is-it-possible-to-pass-parameters-by-reference-using-call-user-func-array)

[PHP: call_user_func_array: pass by reference issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905800/php-call-user-func-array-pass-by-reference-issue)

Answer (score 1):

You could manually convert the arguments like so.

```
public function __call($method, $arguments) {
  $referenceable_arguments = array();
  // Gets around a limitation in PHP.
  foreach ($arguments as &$argument) {
    $referenceable_arguments[] = &$argument;
  }
  return call_user_func_array(array($this->delegate, $method), $referenceable_arguments);
}
```